# gtable rbind/cbind with fixed coordinates

Tags: r, plot

Plot widths (or heights) can be maintained across multiple grob objects using rbind/cbind from gtable but it would be nice to keep fixed coordinates for some of the grobs.  This would be handy for combining plots with cartesian and geographic coordinates. The plot widths (or heights) are maintained correctly in all the examples I've seen but the fixed coordinates are not, depending on plot order.

Consider the example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

states <- map_data('state')
rands <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

# first plot, coord fixed
p1 <- ggplot(states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  coord_fixed()

# second plot, not fixed
p2 <- ggplot(rands, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() 

# plot after combining with rbind
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size = 'last'))
```

[image]
This is okay but note the difference if the plot order is switched:

```
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p2), ggplotGrob(p1), size = 'last'))
```

[image]
Placing the map plot second removes the fixed coordinate system. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't know if it's enough for you, but grid.arrange(p1, p2) allows you to switch the plots, but the size are not the same..

Comment: @MLavoie yes, that works for the aspect ratios but I need the same widths.